# The Three.js Developer Tools always displays waiting for a scene to be observed

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

When I use vite + vue3 to create a three application, I often use three to check the situation in the scene JS developer tools, but recently the plug-in always shows waiting for a scene to be observed, but the scene has indeed been loaded. And this situation is normal occasionally (very low frequency)

Comment: Please add more details, or even a [repro], too hard to debug with just that.